# Why isn't there a constant within the sinusoidals in solutions to 2nd Order ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

In reading my partial differential equations textbook an ODE was solved in the following way:
$$
\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}=\left(\frac{n\pi}{H}\right)^2 h \hspace{1cm} h = \sinh\left(\frac{n\pi(x-L)}{H}\right)
$$
In this case, sinh can be reduced to the sum of sinh and cosh terms in $x$, not $(x-L)$, but it got me thinking about why we don't include a constant inside of sine and cosine functions, for example, in the general solution for negative eigenvalue:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -k^2 y \hspace{1cm} y=c_1\cos(kx+c_2) + c_3 \sin(kx+c_4)
$$
This is my question - what, exactly, makes it unnecessary to include these additional constants $c_2$ and $c_4$?

Comment: Angle sum formulas make it so that you can convert from one form into the other. There is no preference for one form over another except to perhaps accentuate certain aspects of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a second-order ODE should have a two-parameter family of solutions.  In your second ODE you don't need $c_2$ and $c_4$ because with $c_1$ and $c_3$ you already have a two-parameter family.  Indeed, expanding your sin and cos terms and rearranging gives you something of the same form without the $c_2$ and $c_4$:

$$c_1 \cos(kx + c_2) + c_3 \sin(kx + c_4) = b_1 \cos(kx) + b_2 \sin(kx) $$
where
$$ b_1 = c_1 \cos(c_2) + c_3 \sin(c_4),\ b_2 = - c_1 \sin(c_2) + c_3 \cos(c_4) $$

As for your first equation, you have one parameter $L$, but you need another: you could write
$$ y = c \sinh \left(\frac{n\pi (x-L)}{H}\right) $$